# File descriptor 255 for terminal?

Tags: bash, filesystem, proc

I was learning about the `proc` filesystem mechanism and I randomly tried to check the file descriptors of bash itself. Can someone explain what the file descriptor number 255 doing here (like I understand what 0,1,2 mean but I have no idea what 255 is in this case) ?

```
sc@HP-ProBook:~$ ls -l /proc/11783/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 sc sc 64 Feb 23 15:40 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 sc sc 64 Feb 23 15:40 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 sc sc 64 Feb 23 15:40 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 sc sc 64 Feb 23 15:48 255 -> /dev/pts/2
```

Comment: See [In Bash, what is file descriptor 255 for, can I use it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/475389/251553) over on Unix&Linux.